# how to remove the limit of partitions per node in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, partitioning

I have a partitioned table in Hive. And for each node I have set the partitions limit to 2000.

```
set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode=2000
```

Now that after 2000 is reached, I am facing a problem. So i am trying to understand if there a possibility to remove this limitation?

Simply I don't want to set any value for `hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode` It should handle any number of partitions.

So could someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 3):

I met this problem before. Add distribute by partition_column at the end of the SQL .

```
insert overwrite table table_A partition (date_id)
select xxxxxxxx
from table_B
distribute by date_id;
```

with "distribute by", same date_id value will be shuffled into one reducer. so   a reducer may process several date_id instead of random date_id ( this may  include all date_id ) .

Comment: How does `distribute by` connected with  dynamic partitions limit? Distribute or not distribute the number of partitions dynamically created will be the same. Distribute by can help to reduce memory consumption.

Comment: distribute by partition_column can redistribute data and the data with same partition will be shuffled into one reducer .

Comment: This will not change the number of partitions per node

Comment: it's too hard for me to explain this in english, may be you can write a sample SQL.

Comment: If your data contain 15000 different partition keys, how many partitions will be created after load? With `distribute by` and without it?

Comment: both will create 15000 partitions but without distribute by,  partition_A may created by 100 node, each node generate 1% data  and each node will +1 partition in hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode ,  with distribute by, all data in partition_A will be process by one node and this node only process a certain data volume. so , this will reduce partitions created by this node .

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! Finally I have found the same in the documentation:  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Tutorial

Comment: @MikeGan : Can you add this explanation in the comment into the answer, so that others could easily read it in the answer at a go, than expanding the comments

Comment: yes, please edit your answer and I will undo my downwote

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, that can't be done, Hive [enforces](https://documentation.altiscale.com/changing-hive-dynamic-partition-limits) a limit in the number of dynamic partitions that it can create. Up to my knowledge, this limitation has to do with the fact that each partition is stored in a separate HDFS directory, so the number of them is somehow bounded in advance to prevent performance issues.